# What does scope: [variable-name]='@' mean in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I hate asking stupid questions but unfortunately, it appears the AngularJS documentation writers forgot to clarify everything.

When creating a directive, you can link variables in your directive to those in your HTML by the following code:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('someModule', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '...',
    scope: {
      x:          '=',
      front:      '@',
      markers:    '=?'
    },
    controller: ...
  }]);
```

I understand that the `'='` after `x` means `x=x` but what do `@` and `?=` mean?

Comment: The only directive guide you'll ever need: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750 - bookmark that for life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to think of the `@` is that it gives you the (*string*) **literal value of the DOM attribute**. Don't worry about calling it a one-way binding, or any of that nonsense - that's just confusing.

If the value happens to be interpolated and you check the value before the interpolation, you'll get `"{{something}}"`, but after the interpolation has happened, you'll get the interpolated value.

This differs dramatically from `=`, which is an **expression that will be evaluated against the parent scope** - a way to give an isolate scope access to the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

`@` does mean `one way binding` with directive isolated scope variable.

If the binded scope variable change inside the controller where element has been place will intimate that change to the directive isolated scope, but the change in the directive isolated scope will be not listen by the controller of where directive has placed.

It need an expression to assign value to the isolated scope variable.

**Example**

```
<my-directive foo-id="{{fooId}}"></my-directive>
```

**Directive**

```
scope: {
   'fooId': '@'
}
```

When there is change in fooId of directive, the expression will get evaluated and sends that value to the `fooId` of isolated scope variable. You could access that isolated scope using `scope.fooId`. If you change `scope.fooId` from directive that will change the binding of `fooId` variable which is there in parent controller where directive has place. Thats why its called as one way binding as it don't udpate a binding in reverse way.

### '=?'

Its meaning is you could use `=` two way binding but the value of attribute could be optional `?` after `=` indicates it is an optional field.

If you use only `=` without `?` then you much need to provide value of variable reference inside that attribute. That doesn't happen then angular will throw an `noassign` error by angular.